# How can I get a for loop to output once rather than every iteration?

Tags: bash, for-loop, nmap

I've made this simple bash script to run a ping scan and grab MAC addresses active on my network, output to a file, and then compare that file against a file with a list of known MAC addresses I grabbed from my ARP table in my router.

Rather than echo a result for each line that it iterates, how can I make the for loop spit out one output like "All Devices are familiar on your network"?

current code:

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24 | grep "MAC" | awk '{print $3}'| sort > $HOME/Desktop/arp.txt

readarray -t mac <$HOME/Desktop/arptable.txt

for address in "${mac[@]}"; do
    if grep -Fxq "$address" $HOME/Desktop/arptable.txt;
    then 
        echo "$address is a known network device"
    else
        echo "WARNING: $address is an unknown device on the network"
    fi
done
```

and my current output looks like:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a known network device
```

Disclamer: This is just a project and not used as a serious security tool.

Comment: Should just need a boolean to be set if the else condition ever occurs, and print "All Devices are familiar on your network" - or the opposite - based on that (after the loop, however you do an if statement in bash).

Comment: You can rewrite over the same line everytime, also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still want to print out the `WARNING` messages ... keep track of the number of successes and if equal to the number of entries in the array `mac[]` then print your desired message, eg:

```
found=0

for address in "${mac[@]}"; do
    if grep -Fxq "$address" $HOME/Desktop/arptable.txt;
    then 
        ((found++))
    else
        echo "WARNING: $address is an unknown device on the network"
    fi
done 

[[ "${found}" -eq "${#max[@]}" ]] && echo "All Devices are familiar on your network"
```

Alternatively, clear a flag if you generate any `WARNING` messages:

```
foundall=true

for address in "${mac[@]}"; do
    if ! grep -Fxq "$address" $HOME/Desktop/arptable.txt;
    then 
        echo "WARNING: $address is an unknown device on the network"
        foundall=false
    fi
done 

[[ "${foundall}" == 'true' ]] && echo "All Devices are familiar on your network"
```

Comment: Option 2 is the concept I was expressing in my pseudocode answer, but both of these answers are useful.

Comment: @markp-fuso Ah, will do. This was my first post so I was not aware.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode (I do not do bash, don't know syntax):

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24 | grep "MAC" | awk '{print $3}'| sort > $HOME/Desktop/arp.txt

readarray -t mac <$HOME/Desktop/arptable.txt

# everythingGood = true
for address in "${mac[@]}"; do
    if grep -Fxq "$address" $HOME/Desktop/arptable.txt;
    then 
    else
        # everythingGood = false
        # some code here maybe to store which ones failed
    fi
done 

# if everythingGood
    # echo "All Devices are familiar on your network"
# else
    # echo "WARNING: $address is an unknown device on the network"
```